Is it appropriate to ask former mentors/professors to peer review a study?
I conducted research with my former professors and mentors during my internship and master's program at my former institution. We published one paper together, of which I was the lead author. Three years later during my PhD training, I recommended them as reviewers for a manuscript I also led. I have a great deal of respect for my former mentors and implicitly trust their objective feedback. However, given my previous relationship with them, I wonder whether this was a conflict of interest.

Review for whom?  Just yourself or as a recommendation to an editor?

Recommendations to an editor for publication

I don't think I've ever seen a scenario where one could choose their own peer reviewers. Recommend or suggest, yes, but not select. It would be up to the editor to choose reviewers, and they can decide if the conflict is an issue as long as they're informed of the situation. Most reviewing is done blinded in some way to avoid this sort of thing - it's typically deemed inappropriate for authors to even know who is reviewing their paper, much less choose them. I'm surprised you have the opportunity to pick your own reviewers, regardless of who you choose.

Certainly you can recommend them to an editor as possible reviewers so long as you make your prior associations clear. You don't make the choice, the editor does, relieving you of any conflict of interest. But that notice of prior relationships is essential to avoid ethical issues.
One might misunderstand the request to nominate reviewers a bit, though. It is (I hope) the editor that makes the choices.
Such people are probably competent in the topic to do a good job and the editor will be aware that other, more independent, review might be needed.
I think the practice of asking authors to nominate reviewers is fairly common, especially for narrow research topics where the editor may not know who the obvious candidates are.

I did not disclose, though I am sure they likely may have disclosed our prior association with the editor-in-chief given that one of my reviewers is an editor at the same journal.

You can still make the disclosure. If you don't, then it raises conflict of interest issues. Make it explicit.

You should definitely disclose this when suggesting the reviewer. Example.

We ask reviewers to declare any potential conflicts of interest and email the journal Editorial Office if they are unsure if something constitutes a potential conflict of interest. Possible conflicts of interest include (but are not limited to):

Reviewer works in the same institute as one of the authors;
Reviewer is a co-author, collaborator, joint grant holder, or has any other academic link, with any of the authors within the past three years;
Reviewer has a close personal relationship, rivalry or antipathy to any of the authors;
Reviewer may in any way gain or lose financially from publication of the paper;
Reviewer has any other non-financial conflicts of interest (political, personal, religious, ideological, academic, intellectual, commercial or any other) with any of the authors.

Reviewers should disclose any conflicts of interest that may be perceived as bias for or against the paper or authors.

The two highlighted bullet points both count against your case. It doesn't mean they won't be eligible to review, the editor might choose to invite them anyway, but they will definitely want to know the reviewer might be biased (and hence you should disclose).
